# checkboard javafx logical errors

Tags: java, javafx

This is the code to produce a checkboard by taking two images from google,but when I run it it tells me multiple Exception. I don't know what I did wrong because there are no syntax errors, there are logical ones.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class CheckBoard extends Application{

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

       ImageView imag = new      ImageView("https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/
       4034/4544827697_6f73866999_b.jpg");
       ImageView imag1 = new         ImageView("https://upload.
       wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Red.svg/2000px-Red.svg.png");
       GridPane pane = new GridPane();
       imag1.setFitHeight(50);
       imag1.setFitWidth(50);
       imag.setFitHeight(50);
       imag.setFitWidth(50);

       for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
       {
           for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
           {
               if(j%2==0) pane.add(imag, i, j);
               else pane.add(imag1, i, j);
           }
       }

       Scene scene= new Scene(pane,600,600);
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.show();
    }


}
```

Comment: What are the exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting exceptions like the following

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Grid hgap=0.0, vgap=0.0, alignment=TOP_LEFT
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Unknown Source)
...
```

because you can not add a `Node` (your `ImageView`) to more than one parent. You need to load the images and then create separate `ImageViews` for each cell:

```
...
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

   Image image = new Image("https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4034/4544827697_6f73866999_b.jpg");
   Image image1 = new Image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Red.svg/2000px-Red.svg.png");

   GridPane pane = new GridPane();
   for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
       for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
           ImageView view;
           if(j % 2 == 0) {
               view = new ImageView(image);
           }
           else {
               view = new ImageView(image1);
           }

           view.setFitHeight(50);
           view.setFitWidth(50);
           pane.add(view, i, j);
       }
   }
}
...
```

On a side note, the images you use seem to be read and black squares only - I assume that you want to use different images in your actual application, but if you really want to use colored rectangles only you might be better using a `Rectangle` instead of an `Image`.